# Working code not compiling on hackerrank

Tags: java

I am working on a small piece of code that converts string into an integer and throw an exception if it doesn't meet the integer criteria. The code doesn't work fine on hackerrank for some reason. Can anyone share your inputs if you have faced something similar. Thanks.

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class StringtoInt {     
    public static long parseLong(String str) {
        long result = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ ) {
            result = result * 10 + str.charAt(i) - '0';
            if( !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) )
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }    
        return result;
    }   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( parseLong( "12345" ) );
}

}
```

Errors I get when compiled on hackerrank :-

[image]

Errors :-

[image]

Comment: That's not valid Java - it won't compile with any valid Java compiler.

Comment: My bad that was a typo... corrected it to "12345"

Comment: @Teja Now there are no compiler errors

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ but it doesnt work on hackerrank... :(

Comment: And how sure are you that the code that fails on hackerrank is the *working* code rather than the original invalid code? (That's the problem with this sort of thing... we can't tell "just typo" errors from the real thing.)

Comment: What means: "The code doesn't work fine " please describe in detail

Comment: I added a screen-shot. pls check it...

Comment: Your screenshot does not help, a paste of the "error" would be more helpful

Comment: What's in lines 1-8?

Comment: There is no code in lines 1-8. Code itself starts from line 9.

Comment: Have you tried submitting it without the line 9 comment? Perhaps hackerrank uses a homegrown compiler that gets confused when you combine `/* ... */`, `//`, and `;` in one line.

Comment: Does hackerrank allow imports?

Comment: Its still the same. failing for all three packages.

Comment: Does it compile if you use specific imports instead of star imports?

Comment: It's still the same....

Comment: So have you tried without those first 8 lines that you haven't shown us? Note that the error you're seeing is one you'll get if you try to add an import after a class declaration. Are you sure HackerRank hasn't actually said you should just assume all the code you write is already inside a class declaration?

Comment: There is nothing in the first 8 lines @JonSkeet There are no instructions in specific to the declarations that need to be done in hackerrank. I am given a coding problem and asked to solve it using java 7 or python 2.

Comment: Well I've just copied and pasted that code directly into Hackerrank's Java editor and not seen the error you're getting... is this a specific challenge you can link to? If we can't reproduce the problem, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: I got this coding problem on hackerrank and asked to solve it this way. If its a valid integer then display it otherwise produce an exception. I didn't even get to a point to test my code on any test cases. At first step itself the code doesnt compile which is breaking my progress.

Comment: Can anybody help me with my problem?